# Real automated and unattended wordpress upgrade including plugins

Tags: updates, upgrade, automatic-updates, cron

I'm looking for a truly automated way to upgrade wordpress and its plugins, something that i could put in the crontab and configure it to run daily.

I have several wordpress plugins (>20) and a multi-site wordpress installation and I don't want to spend my time doing the upgrades.

I am willing to take the risk of a upgrade failure and have the sites offline until I manually resolve the problem.

Please do not post solutions that are requiring manual intervention in order to make the update/upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any solutions for iterating through and automatically updating your list of plug-ins, but my guess is that any system that can automatically update WordPress itself can be modified to update everything in fairly short order.

That said, I know of two good ways to update WordPress automatically:

### [WP Remote](http://wpremote.com)

This is an online service that allows you to remotely monitor and update WordPress when needed.  From the initial description I received (I haven't had the opportunity to test it myself), you can set the system to update things automatically without your intervention.

### [WordPress Automatic Upgrade](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-automatic-upgrade/)

I have several clients who swear by this plug-in.  It will automatically upgrade WordPress (not your plug-ins) whenever an update becomes available.

---

#### Update 7/13/11

Another option, since you're already using cron to schedule the update, is to script it and use Subversion.

If you install WordPress via Subversion, you can just run `svn up` to automatically update to the latest version.  This will update your files, but not the database ... so you'll need to script a hit to the code that runs the db update as well.

Plugins will work the same way.  Rather than using the built-in installer, check out the plugins you're using via Subversion and iterate through the `/plugins` folder with an `svn up` command to keep them up to date.

Some of my sites are using private plugins that are hosted on GitHub - I use the same process there.  I check out the plugin using `git clone` and just run `git pull` on a cron to keep them up to date with the latest version.

Comment: The old WordPress Automatic Upgrade plugin is bad and should never be used. It will not upgrade properly past 3.2 or so. If you have any clients on it, get them off it, ASAP. For anybody who did use it and found that their visual editor isn't working properly anymore: a) remove the plugin, b) do the re-install in the normal built-in upgrader. This will fix the installation. Prime indicator of this problem is that the fullscreen button will be missing in the editor for 3.2.